# Flutter slider thumb shap to be star

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image]

I need to achieve set this star but the slider has no option for it please help. Flutter

Flutter Slider look a lot about this issue but did not find

Comment: I guess you will have to write your own widget for it. Based on a GestureDetector so that you can make it interactive for sliding

Comment: there is a [thumbShape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/thumbShape.html) for that purpose - the docs say: "The shape that will be used to draw the Slider's thumb.

The default value is RoundSliderThumbShape"